# Neovim Rust LSP diagnostics no longer working in buffers

Tags: rust, neovim

Something has caused my Rust language tools to stop working as expected recently. I hadn't been in a Rust file for about 2 weeks, came back and I no longer have all the diagnostic info from the language server in the buffer. No gutter hints, no underlines, no LSP-Saga goodness. Oddly I still have some inlay hints. ?? I could use some help troubleshooting where to dig on this.

### Nvim version:

NVIM v0.8.0-1210-gd367ed9b2

LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3

### Packer installs related to rust:

- nvim-lspconfig (though not using it to configure rust, see tools below)
- Mason and mason-lspconfig
- simrat39/rust-tools

Rust-Analyzer and codelldb installed through Mason and updated

So far I have tried removing rust-tools and and configuring through lspconfigs. No luck. I also confirmed with :LspInfo that the language server is running and attached with both config options. I removed LSPSaga, combed through everything touching `vim.diagnostic` and turned things off / back on, no love there either.

The strange thing is I still have my Typescript, Lua, Svelte and Go support, full featured and totally unchanged, so it's more than likely something specific to Rust. I did run PackerSync a few times because I was playing with themes and saw some updates on other plugins that I didn't pay a lot of attention to. No new issues on any of the github repos related to Rust either, at least not with this issue. Something changed somewhere, but I could definitely use some direction tracking it down.

Any thoughts?

### Edit

I was able to get partial support back. I did this by uninstalling the language server with Mason, then installing an older version directly within linux and adding it to $PATH. At this point things some of the things turned back on, but not all. I then removed the binary from $PATH and reinstalled the latest version with Mason, and the things that started working again kept working.

This one has me stumped, but I got *enough* functionality back to work comfortably again.